# Как сделать событие в JS чтоб вызывался только один ключ из объекта? При следующем нажатии следуюющий ключ

Tags: javascript, циклы, события

```
let list = {
    'cat': 'кот',
    'dog': 'собака',
    'door': 'дверь'
};
let card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.onclick = function () {
    for (let key in list) {
        card.innerHTML = key + " ";
    }
}
card.onclick = function () {
    for (let key in list) {
        card.innerHTML = list[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойстве `.onclick` может храниться ссылка только на одну функцию. Ваш второй onclick стирает предыдущую. Такое в принципе не надо делать - нужно оформлять всё в одной функции, но если иногда хочется в разных местах в коде добавить несколько одинаковых событий на одну кнопку, используют `addEventListener`. Хорошо бы сразу к нему привыкнуть и забыть про onclick.

---

Нужно собрать массив из значений объекта (*) и сделать обычную переменную-счетчик, которая будет увеличиваться после каждого клика и указывать на следующий элемент.

(*) Замечание: Ничто не гарантирует, что в массиве значения окажутся в том же порядке, в котором были добавлены в объект. Если порядок элементов важен - изначально стоит работать только с массивом.

```js
let list = {
  cat: "кот",
  dog: "собака",
  door: "дверь",
};

list = Object.values(list); // ["кот", "собака", "дверь"]
let card = document.querySelector(".card");
let counter = 0;

card.addEventListener('click', function tmp() {
  card.textContent += (" " + list[ counter++ ]); 
  // Добавляем элемент из массива и одновременно увеличиваем counter на 1
  
  if( !list[ counter ] ) { // Если следующего элемента в массиве нет
    card.textContent += " Конец!";
    card.removeEventListener('click', tmp); // Удалить обработчик клика.
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">&gt;&gt; </div>
```

`Object.values(list);` делает то же самое, что и

```
let arr = [];
for( let key in list ) {
  arr.push( list[key] );
}
```

P.s. http://learn.javascript.ru/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, но тогда нужно заменить наименование ключей.

```js
let list = {
  1: 'кот',
  2: 'собака',
  3: 'дверь'
};

let div = document.querySelectorAll('div');

let count = 1;

div[0].onclick = function a() {
  if (count > Object.keys(list).length) count = 1;
  console.log(list[count]);
  count++;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"> Кликни меня </div>
```

Comment: `count = ( ++count ) % arr.length` - есть еще такой трюк) Если нужно делать круги.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME смотрел и не мог понять, а потом как понял))